# 2 java agents conflicting with each other

Tags: java, java-8, instrumentation, javassist, javaagents

I want to instrument getMessage() method of Throwable class and output some custom message to System.out or logger. I have written an agent called FirstAgent that is working fine as expected. Now my agent needs to sit along with and complement another vendor's agent. When I attach both agents (my agent and another vendor's agent) to JVM, my instrumented changes in getMessage() of Throwable class are lost. When attached in silo, these two agents are working fine.

I have recreated this problem using FirstAgent and SecondAgent (code attached). Based on the order of the agents, FirstAgent is loaded first and SecondAgent is loaded next. What I noticed is that when FirstAgent is loaded, it loads Throwable class, instruments, and exits. Next, When SecondAgent loads Throwable class, it is not loading the class definition with FirstAgent's instrumented changes. It is loading the original Throwable class (without FirstAgent's instrumented changes), instrumenting with its own changes, and exiting. In the process, Throwable class is losing FirstAgent's instrumented changes.

Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;
import javassist.Modifier;

public class FirstAgent implements ClassFileTransformer {

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
        try {
            String agentJarLocation = new File(
                    FirstAgent.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()).getPath();
            inst.appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch(new JarFile(agentJarLocation));
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Class<?> targetClazz = Class.forName("java.lang.Throwable");
            FirstAgent fa = new FirstAgent();
            try {
                inst.addTransformer(fa, true);
                inst.retransformClasses(targetClazz);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to transform [" + targetClazz.getName() + "]", ex);
            } finally {
                inst.removeTransformer(fa);
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        byte[] byteCode = classfileBuffer;
        try {
            ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
            CtClass ctClass = classPool.makeClass(new ByteArrayInputStream(classfileBuffer));
            CtMethod[] methods = ctClass.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (CtMethod method : methods) {
                if (method.getName().contains("getMessage") && Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
                    method.insertBefore("System.out.println(\"First Custome Message\");");
                }
            }
            byteCode = ctClass.toBytecode();
            ctClass.detach();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return byteCode;
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;
import javassist.Modifier;

public class SecondAgent implements ClassFileTransformer {

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
        try {
            String agentJarLocation = new File(
                    SecondAgent.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()).getPath();
            inst.appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch(new JarFile(agentJarLocation));
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Class<?> targetClazz = Class.forName("java.lang.Throwable");
            SecondAgent sa = new SecondAgent();
            try {
                inst.addTransformer(sa, true);
                inst.retransformClasses(targetClazz);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to transform [" + targetClazz.getName() + "]", ex);
            } finally {
                inst.removeTransformer(sa);
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        byte[] byteCode = classfileBuffer;
        try {
            ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
            CtClass ctClass = classPool.makeClass(new ByteArrayInputStream(classfileBuffer));
            CtMethod[] methods = ctClass.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (CtMethod method : methods) {
                if (method.getName().contains("getMessage") && Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
                    method.insertBefore("System.out.println(\"Secocnd Custome Message\");");
                }
            }
            byteCode = ctClass.toBytecode();
            ctClass.detach();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return byteCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to do, what do you hope to achieve by modifying the output from `Throwable` itself? Rather, what is it that you'll be using this for?

Comment: @Rogue I am developer of a monitoring solution that adds more context to logging. I wrote FirstAgent and SecondAgent to only demonstrate or recreate the problem for better understanding.

Comment: That’s how `retransformClasses` works: all registered transformers are asked one after the other to perform their transformation, getting the result of the previous transformer as input (the first gets the original bytes). Since your first Agent has unregistered its transformer, it isn’t asked in the second round. Don’t confuse this operation with `redefineClasses`. And generally, transformers should check the name of the class, instead of trying to transform everything the are called for.

Comment: There is almost never a reason to unregister a transformer. If you want to keep the changes, leave the transformer registered. If you want to discard your changes, unregister your transformer, and retransform. If your agent is not the only agent in the VM, expect that any class can be retransformed at any time. You should handle this gracefully, usually by making the transform [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Comment: @Holgar and Johannes Yes, it is indeed unregistration of the transformer that is causing the problem. After removing removeTransformer() line, it's working as expected. Yes, the class name should be checked before the transformation. I agree. Very much appreciated.